# why inverse in diffie-hellman protocol will not give same value?

Tags: diffie-hellman, elgamal-encryption

Security of diffie hellman protocol is $K=g^{ab}$.if sender want to calculate value of $b$(given $a$) he can do $g^{{{ab}^b}^{-1}}$(where K=$g^{ab}$) which will give $g^{a}$ as we are cancelling value of $b$ by finding its inverse. but it is not cancelling the value of $b$ and not give the output $g^a$. can any one explain why, while in ElGamal decryption in same way give plain text ($m=c2 *g^{ab}^-1$)

Comment: g^{{ab}^b}^-1 $\:$ is not canceling the value of $b$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: In case of ElGamal we decrypt the cipher text by inverting m=c*(g^ab)^-1 then why not in diffie-hellman

Comment: In Diffie-Hellman, we usually want to encrypt data that doesn't fit in a single group element. $\hspace{.86 in}$

Comment: For more clarity could you update your question? Do you mean why $g^{a(bb^{-1})} !=g^a\bmod P$ or why $g^{(abb)^{-1}} !=g^a\bmod P$.

Comment: Yes, like @neverwalkaloner mentioned, your exponentiation formula is not really clear. Please add some parentheses to make the order clear.

Comment: If you don't know $b$, how do you want to use $b^{-1}$?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I think the edit destroyed the original question. Originally the question was to obtain $g^a$ by computing $(K^b)^{-1}$.

Comment: @DrLecter: Where was this edit? The edit history looks perfectly reasonable to me?

Comment: @figlesquidge oh, maybe I thought I have seen braces or interpreted it as if the OP meant $(K^b)^{-1}$ (because that made sense in the context of the remainder of the question).

Answer (score 3):

In DH if you want to compute $g^a$ from $K$ you have to know $b$ (which the legitimate receiver of $g^a$ clearly knowns, so this does not really make sence). This party can compute the inverse of $b$, namely $b^{-1}$, and then compute $g^a=K^{b^{-1}}$. Note that this is not the same as $(K^b)^{-1}=(g^{ab})^{-1}$ (as I will discuss below). But that is not related to the security of DH.

The security behind DH is the computational DH problem, i.e., an eavesdropper learning $g^a$ and $g^b$ cannot compute the shared secret $K=g^{ab}$. But clearly the two parties doing the exchange can, as they hold $b$ and $a$ respectively. So for instance the party holding $a$ and received $g^b$ can compute $(g^a)^b$. Both parties holding $K$ can then use this shared secret to derive some symmetric key for encryption of any messages they want to communicate.

Note that in ElGamal (which may be seen as a non-interactive DH using the public key as static DH key of the receiver) you have $(c_1,c_2)=(g^k,mg^{xk})$ as a ciphertext and $h=g^x$ as the public key and $x$ as the secret key. This means that you encrypt a message using the DH key. Then you decrypt as $m=c_2\cdot (c_1^x)^{-1}$. Note that $(c_1^x)^{-1}=(g^{xk})^{-1}$ which is the inverse of $g^{xk}$ and will cancel out in the decryption as $g^{xk} \cdot (g^{xk})^{-1}=1$.

Note that nobody would use ElGamal to directly encrypt messages, but one will use [hybrid encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem), i.e., use ElGamal to encrypt a random symmetric key and use the symmetric key to encrypt the messages.

Why is it a different thing to compute either $(g^{ab})^{b^{-1}}$ or $((g^{ab})^b)^{-1}$? Well, I think your problem is that you should write the parenthesis as I have done it above, since these are two different things.

Now, $K^{b^{-1}}=(g^{ab})^{b^{-1}}=g^{abb^{-1}}$, i.e., here you exponentiate $K=g^{ab}$ with the element $b^{-1}$ (the invese of $b$) and since $bb^{-1}=1$ you obtain $g^{a}$. In the second case you have $(K^b)^{-1}=((g^{ab})^b)^{-1}=(g^{abb})^{-1}$, i.e., you exponentiate $K=g^{ab}$ with $b$ and then compute the inverse of the resulting element, which does not give you $g^a$ as a result, but $(g^{abb})^{-1}$ which is not equal to $g^a$.

For a concrete setting, if you work in the group ${\mathbb Z}_p^*$ with $p$ being prime and use a generator $g$ of  ${\mathbb Z}_p^*$, then arithmetic is done modulo $p$. So inverses of elements, e.g. $(g^{ab})^{-1}$, are computed in ${\mathbb Z}_p^*$. **But**, be careful, operations on elements in the exponent of $g$ ($g$ generates the group of order $p-1$), e.g., computing $b^{-1}$ (if you want to compute $(g^{ab})^{b^{-1}}$) are done modulo $p-1$. This clearly requires that $b$ is co-prime to $p-1$, i.e., $\gcd(b,p-1)=1$, that the multiplicative inverse $b^{-1}$ of $b$ exists.

Comment: that what is my question why g^a!=(k^b)^-1

Comment: I suppose you are not right. Look at my answer, I tried to explain why this is not correct.

Comment: @Aria I clarified it a bit more.

Comment: in case of ElGamal $g^{x k}.g^{xk}^-1 = 1 why not in K^{b}^−1= g^{abb}^−1

Comment: I do not see your point, $(K^b)^{-1}=(g^{abb})^{-1}$. But the thing is that $(g^{abb})^{-1}\neq g^a$.

Comment: @Aria I tried to clarify it a bit more. I think you should use parenthesis to eliminate your confusion. Do you try a concrete example you are working on? Because then, I would guess you compute the inverses in the wrong way.